# Should two different TV series with the same name have the same tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a TV series called Shameless that has an American version and British version. Should both of them have the same tag called [shameless](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shameless)? Or should they have separate tags like [shameless-us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shameless-us) and [shameless-uk](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shameless-uk) ?

Comment: Those seem perfectly logical to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @wbogacz says in the comments; use common sense.  If your question is about the UK version, tag it with that.

Similarly with the US version.

The same goes for 'reboot' series that share a name.  For example:  [friday-the-13th](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friday-the-13th) is about the original wheras [friday-the-13th-2009](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friday-the-13th-2009) is about the reboot.