# Please change [Samsara] tag

Tags: support, tags

Can someone with enough rep edit [samsara](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsara) to be [samsara-2001](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsara-2001) in accordance with [this meta answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1696/20086)), then add in the tag info that this is about the 2001 movie https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196069/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2.

It would be helpful to at the same time create [samsara-2011](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsara-2011) to reference the 2011 documentary https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0770802/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

(Request triggered by [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92865/what-is-the-message-of-the-movie-samsara))

Comment: Why to create samsara 2011 tag when there is no question about it

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Many people misinterpret and goes towards 'samsara-2011' link. It happened already. Please check comments in question [Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92865/what-is-the-message-of-the-movie-samsara?noredirect=1#comment156822_92865)

Comment: We can't create tag of a show/film which have no question

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Please don't create it, If possible you can edit and rename `Samsara` to `Samsara-2001`

Comment: @AnkitSharma, otherwise you can allow me to add release date in my question's content. (I had already added it previously but moderator deleted that information)

Comment: @DDD the way you added the detail was bit awkward and unesasary, anyways edited it to make it clear with link

Comment: @AnkitSharma, That is nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think you missed a crucial part in this. We don't add year appendaged to tags just because there is some possible film existing that might bear that name, too. In fact, there's probably on average about 17 existing films for each phrase in the English language.

We only do that once we actually *have* both movies' tags. And this in turn requires questions to be asked about both movies. This is also the reason why it is *technically impossible* to create a tag for the 2011 documentary right now.

*If* your actual point is that we should instead always add year appendages to *every* film tag ever, this might be a reasonable discussion to have at a broader scope, but this support request about a single instance isn't that discussion.