# Tag creation: [Suspiria-2018] and [Suspiria-1977]

Tags: discussion, tags

Seeing that there are 2 movies with the exact same name shall I create these tags to help differentiate them? (not that there are billions of questions for these anyway, so no rush...)

Comment: Right now we are using the same tag [tag:suspiria] for both.

Comment: Related (if not even exact duplicate): [Rules for multiple media using the same name](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1427/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson fair enough, very much related. Not exact dupe just because I'm specifically asking for these 2 tags to be edited / created, if not for that I'd close the question myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are more than one movie or TV show with the same name, the release year should be added in the tag in order to identify which version of movie or show they are about.

There are five questions at the moment tagged as [suspiria](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspiria). All questions clearly mention which one they are about. One doesn't but we can deduce which one they might be asking about.

There are two questions about 1977 Suspiria and three about 2018 Suspiria. I have tagged these three with [suspiria-2018](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspiria-2018).

Comment: But for clarity / consistency we should, right? I also posted a new discussion on an idea I had for tags+movie versions https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/should-we-have-year-tags

Comment: Yes, for clarity.

Comment: I also renamed `suspiria` to `suspiria-1977`.