# Corrections for Tag: Rush

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag named [rush](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rush). It has been assigned to two questions, both of them on the movie Rush (2013). Unfortunately there is also a movie Rush (1992), starring Jason Patrick and Jennifer Jason Lee. While I can't find any questions on the 1992 movie, there could be some, eventually. What would be the best way to signify which movie this tag is for, within the tag itself.
I would think renaming it to Rush-2013 would do, but either I don't have the rights to do this, or it's not possible (!)?

Comment: Old, generalized discussion about this issue - https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/rules-for-multiple-media-using-the-same-name

Answer (score 2):

At the moment this is a non-problem since as you say, there are no questions on the 1992 movie.

Certainly some tag guidance on the existing tag would be helpful. [Ed. Apparently this was pending approval]

In general, we have tended to operate on the first movie to get a question gets the honour of the *undated* tag but as Catija has pointed out in the linked meta post this does have some issues.

We have the option of retagging the existing 2 questions with [rush-2013](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rush-2013) or just waiting and seeing what happens.

I prefer the latter option.

Comment: If that's the standard, I'm OK with it. It's just there are many instances of something easily 'fixed' in the beginning that later becomes someone else's nightmare.

Comment: @CGCampbell That is true. But tag renaming is actually something that's quite easily fixable without even requiring posts to be edited (as long as people involve the moderators rather than going about it themselves).